# Why is my Cassandra database so slow in reading data? I would like to read 100,000 rows in less than 10s

Tags: python, cassandra

I have a cassandra table 'articles' with 400,000 rows with

```
primary key (source,created_at desc)
```

When I query our data using:

```
select * from articles where source = 'abc' and created_at <= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
```

it takes 8 minutes to load 110,000 rows.

This is extremely slow and I don't know where the error lies.

**I would like to load 100,000 rows in less than 10s.** Not sure if this is possible?

Here some more details:

- I have 3 nodes, `replication factor =2, stragegy=SimpleStrategy`, 4CPU, 32G RAM
- I am using Cassandra-driver-3.0.0. I am not sure if it comes from python or Cassandra since we are also using python.

Here is my CQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE crawler.articles (
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    id text,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY (source, created_at, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC, id ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'sstable_size_in_mb': '160', 'enabled': 'true', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'false', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '86400', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.2', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 604800
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

CREATE INDEX articles_id_idx ON crawler.articles (id);
CREATE INDEX articles_url_idx ON crawler.articles (url);
```

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: You should tell us more about your setup: how many nodes, replication factor, strategy, hardware, etc. And post your CQL schema. Also: are you sure it comes from Cassandra and not from your driver (Python, Java?)?

Comment: I added all the information you requested. Thanks for your fast reply and hope it helps to resolve this.

Comment: Do you perform a lot of deletes?  Do you have alot of tombstones?  What is the MB size of the rows?

Comment: Can you run the query in cqlsh and get the query tracing info?

Comment: I don't delete at all. We therefore don't have any tombstones. I don't know the MB size of the rows. How can I find this out? I would like to load 100,000 rows in less than 10s but are not sure if that is possible.

Comment: @AlecCollier I ran the query but its quite long. How do I best share the tracing info with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to tell the exact problem without knowing the exact configuration.

But you can check following things:

```
Monitor Cassandra for memory consumption and stage throughput.

Set your Memtable thresholds low.

Access Cassandra concurrently.

Don’t store all your data in a single row.

Check for time-outs. 
What is the size of javaHeap?
```

Comment: I added some more information to the post above. Maybe it helps clarify some of the remarks you made.  My java heap is 8GB. Thanks for the help