# Why is my Cassandra Database too slow in reading data? Want to read 100,000 rows in less than 10s

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I have a cassandra table 'articles' with 400,000 rows with

```
primary key (source,created_at desc)
```

When I query our data using:

```
select * from articles where source = 'abc' and created_at <= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
```

it takes 8 minutes to read 110,000 rows.

This is extremely slow and I don't know where the error lies.

**I would like to read 100,000 rows in less than 10s.** Not sure if this is possible?

Here some more details:

```
I have 3 nodes, replication factor =2, stragegy=SimpleStrategy, 4CPU, 32G RAM
I am using Cassandra-driver-3.0.0.
```

I am not sure if it comes from python or Cassandra since we are also using python.

Here is my CQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE crawler.articles (
    source text,
    created_at timestamp,
    id text,
    category text,
    channel text,
    last_crawled timestamp,
    text text,
    thumbnail text,
    title text,
    url text,
    PRIMARY KEY (source, created_at, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC, id ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'sstable_size_in_mb': '160', 'enabled': 'true', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'false', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '86400', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.2', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 604800
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';

CREATE INDEX articles_id_idx ON crawler.articles (id);
CREATE INDEX articles_url_idx ON crawler.articles (url);
```

**Edit:**

I want to query within the last couple of days new articles therefore my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE source = 'any source' 
AND created_at >= '2016-01-08 00:00:00'
```

A sample insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO articles (source,created_at,id,category,channel,last_crawled,text,thumbnail,title,url) 
VALUES ('money',1452417991000,'1290141063','news_video_top','',1452418260000,'','http://inews.gtimg.com/newsapp_ls/0/143487758_150120/0','article title','http://view.inews.qq.com/a/VID2016011002195801');
```

Client code:

```
'''
import sys
import logging
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel

timespan = int(sys.argv[1])
source = str(sys.argv[2])

logging.basicConfig(filename='statistics-%d.log' % (timespan), format='%(asctime)-15s %(filename)s %(name)-8s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class Whitelist(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, *whitelist):
        self.whitelist = [logging.Filter(name) for name in whitelist]

    def filter(self, record):
        return any(f.filter(record) for f in self.whitelist)

for handler in logging.root.handlers:
    handler.addFilter(Whitelist('statistics'))

log = logging.getLogger('statistics')

try:
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pass

    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

    log.info('[%d] connecting cassandra...' % (timespan))
    cluster = Cluster(['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'])
    session = cluster.connect('crawler')

    cluster = Cluster(['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'])
    session_statis = cluster.connect('statistics')

    created_at = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=-timespan)

    print "[%s] FINDING ..." % (datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    statuses = {}

    stmt = session.prepare("select * from articles where source = ? and created_at >= ? ")
    category_stmt = session.prepare('SELECT category FROM channels WHERE source = ? and id = ?')

    rows = session.execute(stmt, [source, created_at])

    for row in rows:
        try:
            if row.channel and source != 'toutiao':
                category = session.execute(category_stmt, ['zhihu' if row.source=='zhihuzero' else row.source, row.channel])
                statuses[row.id] = {'source':row.source, 'timespan': str(timespan), 'id': row.id, 'title':row.title, 'thumbnail':row.thumbnail, 'url':row.url, 'text':row.text, 'created_at':row.created_at, 'category': category[0].category, 'author':'', 'genre':row.category }
            else:
                statuses[row.id] = {'source':row.source, 'timespan': str(timespan), 'id': row.id, 'title':row.title, 'thumbnail':row.thumbnail, 'url':row.url, 'text':row.text, 'created_at':row.created_at, 'category': row.category, 'author':'', 'genre':'' }

        except Exception, e:
            continue

    print "%s weibos ..." % (len(statuses))
    print "[%s] CACULATING ..." % (datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    stmt = session.prepare('SELECT article, MAX(comments) AS comments,MAX(likes) AS likes,MAX(reads) AS reads,MAX(shares) AS shares FROM axes WHERE article = ? AND at >= ?')

    for statuses_id, status in statuses.iteritems():
        rows = session.execute(stmt, [statuses_id, datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=-timespan)])
        for row in rows:
            if source == 'toutiao':
                if not row.article is None:
                    status['reads'] = row.reads
                    status['likes'] = row.likes
                    status['shares'] = row.shares
                    status['comments'] = row.comments
                    status['speed'] = row.comments
                else:
                    status['reads'] = 0
                    status['likes'] = 0
                    status['shares'] = 0
                    status['comments'] = 0
                    status['speed'] = 0
            elif source == 'weibohao':
                if not row.article is None:
                    status['reads'] = row.reads
                    status['likes'] = row.likes
                    status['shares'] = row.shares
                    status['comments'] = row.comments
                    # status['speed'] = row.comments - row.comments_1
                    status['speed'] = row.shares
                else:
                    status['reads'] = 0
                    status['likes'] = 0
                    status['shares'] = 0
                    status['comments'] = 0
                    status['speed'] = 0
            elif source == 'tencent':
                if not row.article is None:
                    status['reads'] = row.reads
                    status['likes'] = row.likes
                    status['shares'] = row.shares
                    status['comments'] = row.comments
                    # status['speed'] = row.comments - row.comments_1
                    status['speed'] = row.comments
                else:
                    status['reads'] = 0
                    status['likes'] = 0
                    status['shares'] = 0
                    status['comments'] = 0
                    status['speed'] = 0
            elif source == 'zhihu':
                if not row.article is None:
                    status['reads'] = row.reads
                    status['likes'] = row.likes
                    status['shares'] = row.shares
                    status['comments'] = row.comments
                    # status['speed'] = row.comments - row.comments_1
                    status['speed'] = row.likes
                else:
                    status['reads'] = 0
                    status['likes'] = 0
                    status['shares'] = 0
                    status['comments'] = 0
                    status['speed'] = 0
            elif source == 'buluo':
                if not row.article is None:
                    status['reads'] = row.reads
                    status['likes'] = row.likes
                    status['shares'] = row.shares
                    status['comments'] = row.comments
                    # status['speed'] = row.comments - row.comments_1
                    status['speed'] = row.reads
                else:
                    status['reads'] = 0
                    status['likes'] = 0
                    status['shares'] = 0
                    status['comments'] = 0
                    status['speed'] = 0
        elif source == 'zhihuzero':
                if not row.article is None:
                    status['reads'] = row.reads
                    status['likes'] = row.likes
                    status['shares'] = row.shares
                    status['comments'] = row.comments
                    # status['speed'] = row.comments - row.comments_1
                    status['speed'] = row.likes
                else:
                    status['reads'] = 0
                    status['likes'] = 0
                    status['shares'] = 0
                    status['comments'] = 0
                    status['speed'] = 0

    statuses = sorted(statuses.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (v['speed'], k), reverse=True)[:1000]

    print "[%s] TRUNCATING ..." % (datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s AND timespan = %s', (source, str(timespan))) #, consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM

    print "[%s] UPDATING ..." % (datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    for i, status in statuses:
        if status['speed'] > 0:
            session_statis.execute('insert into statistics.statistics(source,timespan,id,title,thumbnail,url,text,created_at,category,genre,author,reads,likes,comments,shares,speed) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', (status['source'], status['timespan'], status['id'], status['title'], status['thumbnail'], status['url'], status['text'], status['created_at'], status['category'], status['genre'], status['author'], status['reads'], status['likes'], status['comments'], status['shares'], status['speed']))
        else:
            print status['id'], status['url']

    print "[%s] DONE ..." % (datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    log.info('[%d] done' % (timespan))

except Exception, e:
    print 'except ===:', e
```

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: I've never used Cassandra, but I know a thing or two about storage / retrieval. No matter which software you use, if you use a mechanical hard drive and the data is fragmented then there's nothing you can install, do or think to solve that issue. Your option is to get a faster drive or try and defragment the one you have. All of the databases and NoSQLs are constrained by the speed of the drive. This is why NoSQL appears to be faster - it doesn't really write stuff to the drive, it schedules it for later - which is why we often lose some records.

Comment: Are you trying to query `110,000 rows` in a `single query` or by framing `many queries` by paginating? And also provide a sample insert statement, since as per your schema some columns are in the data type `text`. So, the retrieval time also depends upon the data size of those columns.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram I am trying to query a single query. I provided an insert sample statement in the Edit above. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I am not sure, May be you are suffering the problem described in this [link](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/142key2pkz/performance-problem-with-large-wide-row-inserts-using-cql). Did you monitored the performance by paginating the result set?

Comment: My problem is related to reading not writing. We haven't tried paginating the result set. Is this going to increase our performance a lot? also added our client code please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Cassandra database so slow in reading data? I would like to read 100,000 rows in less than 10s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650283/why-is-my-cassandra-database-so-slow-in-reading-data-i-would-like-to-read-100-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use case is a little unusual. Cassandra is intended more for transactional operations on a small number of rows rather than doing bulk processing like you might do in hadoop.

The way you are doing your query, you are accessing one partition on a single node and transferring the 100K rows to your client. That's a lot of data to move across the network and I'm not sure why you would want to do that. You're doing everything sequentially, so you're getting no parallelism or benefit from having three nodes.

Usually if you want to do bulk processing on a lot of rows in Cassandra, you'd use Spark to do distributed processing on each node rather than sequentially fetch a lot of data to a client.

Also the two indexes you are creating don't look like they will work very well. Cassandra indexes are intended for fields that have a low cardinality, but you appear to be creating indexes on high cardinality fields. Cassandra indexes are very different from indexes in relational databases.

I'd have to see you client code to know if you are doing something inefficiently there. Usually fetching a lot of rows would trigger paging, so I'm not sure how you're handling that.

Comment: I added my client code in the post above, would be great if you could have a look. Also I constantly receive this error message:     ERROR code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}  don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

How are you doing your reads? If you are using synchronous mechanisms the latency between your client app and server limits your throughput. So be sure to use the async mechanism http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async. But be careful and limit the number of inflight requests so you don't overrun your server. Probably keep it equal to number of concurrent_reads in cassandra.yaml. With only 4 cores you probably wont benefit much from increasing it.

The python client isn't the most efficient either, you can be pretty limited on the client side, so may want to utilize your application server more by spinning up multiple instances or using the java driver (https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

Unless your data model is super wide with hotspots (ie partitioning needed as composite with source) or using slow drives/cpu 100,000 in theory could be read on the order of 10s of seconds or less.

Couple notes on schema: Disable row caching, its rarely a good idea. Dont use secondary indexes unless you REALLY know what your doing. You probably need to break up your partition keys, ie ((source, day), created_at, id) then add 2016-01-12 for jan 12th etc as day field.

Comment: I added our client code would be great if you could have a look. Also I constantly receive this error message: ERROR code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'} don't know how to solve this. Your suggestions were really helpful I am now trying to partition the keys to increase performance but not sure how to approach this best. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your data modelling is not optimal. You have three primary keys and two indexes. Cassandra is a write optimised database, meaning every read is costly. Multiple primary keys and indexes will really slow down your throughput. An ideal table has one primary key. If you need to query by multiple parameters, the table needs to be duplicated with the different keys/indexes as the primary key. It will be a compromise between efficiency/data modeling.

IMHO, if you try to model Cassandra like a SQL database, you are going to have a very bad experience with efficiency.

Comment: You are right. I added our client code in  the top post. I am now trying to break up my partition keys with one primary key. Just not sure how to approach this best. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you should think more than twice using a database like cassandra for this kind av small databases with relational use cases. Use for example postgresql , that will make you life much happier.

I a tested one one of our postgresql really large databases and with the selections you indicate on a table with more than 200 columns and approximately a billion rows you will get sub second responses with out any special tuning except of course the relevant indexes

Remember: Cassandra is only relevant for very specialized use cases   .